# Passing an array to a function gets misinterpreted by the evm as value=20 causing INVALID_ARGUMENT error

Tags: solidity, evm, error

I made an effort to cut out all the irrelevant parts of the code and get a minimal version still able to reproduce the error,
these are the 3 smart contracts involved:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

import './ClientBase.sol';
import './ClientETH.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/Clones.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';

contract ClientFactory is Ownable  {
    address immutable public cbImplementation; //ClientBase implementation contract's address
    address immutable public ceImplementation; //ClientETH implementation contract's address    

    constructor(address _cbImplementation, address  _ceImplementation)  {

        cbImplementation = _cbImplementation;
        ceImplementation = _ceImplementation;

    }

 function createClientBase(string[2] calldata uuids, uint[2] calldata target_info, uint[2] calldata vote_costraints,uint [2] calldata evaluation_info)
 external onlyOwner() returns (address) {
        address clone = Clones.clone(cbImplementation);
        address[] memory addresses= new address[](3);
        addresses[0]= msg.sender;
        addresses[1]= msg.sender;
        addresses[2]= msg.sender;
        ClientBase(clone).initialize(addresses, uuids, target_info, vote_costraints, evaluation_info);
        return clone;
    }

        function createClientETH(string[2] calldata uuids, uint[2] calldata target_info, uint[2] calldata vote_costraints,uint [2] calldata evaluation_info ,uint256 _reward,address receiver_addr)
         external onlyOwner() returns (address) {
        address payable clone = payable(Clones.clone(ceImplementation));
        address[] memory addresses= new address[](4);
        addresses[0]= msg.sender;
        addresses[1]= msg.sender;
        addresses[2]= msg.sender;
        addresses[3]= receiver_addr ;
        ClientETH(clone).initialize(addresses, uuids, target_info, vote_costraints, evaluation_info, _reward);
        return clone;
    }
}
```

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol';

contract ClientBase is Initializable{

    address payable  deployer;
    address public oracle_sc_address;
    address public reputation_SC_address;

    string public uuid_receiver;
    string public uuid_task;

    uint  public target_cat;
    uint  public target_score;
    uint  public max_cat; 
    uint  public max_cat_per_vote;
    uint  public num_experts;
    uint  public max_revisions;

    function initialize (address[] calldata addresses, string[2] calldata uuids, uint[2] calldata target_info, uint[2] calldata vote_costraints,uint [2] calldata evaluation_info)
    public initializer
    {

        max_cat=vote_costraints[0];
        max_cat_per_vote=vote_costraints[1];
        deployer=payable(addresses[0]);
        oracle_sc_address = addresses[1];
        reputation_SC_address=addresses[2]; 

        uuid_receiver=uuids[0];
        uuid_task=uuids[1];

        target_cat=target_info[0];
        target_score=target_info[1];

        num_experts=evaluation_info[0];
        max_revisions=evaluation_info[1];

    }

}
```

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

import './ClientBase.sol';
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
contract ClientETH is  ClientBase{

    address  payable public receiver_addr;
    uint256  public reward;

    function initialize (address[] calldata addresses, string[2] calldata uuids, uint[2] calldata target_info, uint[2] calldata vote_costraints,uint [2] calldata evaluation_info ,uint256 _reward)
    external
    {
        super.initialize(addresses,uuids,target_info,vote_costraints,evaluation_info);
            receiver_addr=payable(addresses[3]);
            reward=_reward;
    }
}
```

The method `createClientETH` works perfectly, but the method `createClientBase` gives me

```
decoded input   { "string[2] uuids": [ "14fd1ace-ca15-490e-9a45-8c381a144416", "14fd1ace-ca15-490e-9a45-8c381a144416" ], "uint256[2] target_info": [ "9", "80" ], "uint256[2] vote_costraints": [ "16", "4" ], "uint256[2] evaluation_info": [ "3", "4" ] } 

decoded output  { "error": "Failed to decode output: null: value out of range (argument=\"value\", value=20, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.1.0)" }
```

using tenderly I noticed that the array address on the line `ClientBase(clone).initialize(addresses, uuids, target_info, vote_costraints, evaluation_info);`
for some reason arrives empty,
I see no difference between the code in createClientBase and createClientToken but only the last one works, could you help me solve this? thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

in the end changing the following did the trick:
in ClientBase, from

```
function initialize (address[] calldata addresses, string[2] calldata uuids, uint[2] calldata target_info, uint[2] calldata vote_costraints,uint [2] calldata evaluation_info)
    public initializer
    {
```

to

```
function initialize (address[3] memory addresses, string[2] calldata uuids, uint[2] calldata target_info, uint[2] calldata vote_costraints,uint [2] calldata evaluation_info)
    public initializer
```

and when I call initialize on clientBase I had to change from this

```
ClientBase(clone).initialize(addresses, uuids, target_info, vote_costraints, evaluation_info);
```

to this

```
ClientBase(clone).initialize([msg.sender,msg.sender,msg.sender], uuids, target_info, vote_costraints, evaluation_info);
```

still not sure why the previous version didn't work.